# Use log differentiation to find the derivative of $y$ with respect to $\theta$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
y = \frac{\theta + 2}{\theta \cos \theta}
$$
Having trouble figuring this out. Need $\ln$ and $\log$ for.

Comment: Why do you think you "need" ln and log? Did the question ask you to do it that way or is that your own idea?

Comment: Question has two answer entry boxes, one space for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good exercise in [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule), which says that
$$
\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)' = \frac{u'v - v'u}{v^2}
$$

In your case, $u = \theta + 2$ and $v = \theta \cos \theta$. Can you plug in?

---

For log-differentiation, you have
$$
\ln y(\theta) = \ln\left( \frac{\theta +2}{\theta \cos \theta} \right)
 = \ln(\theta + 2) - \ln(\theta \cos \theta)
 = \ln(\theta + 2) - \ln(\theta) - \ln(\cos \theta)
$$
Can you now differentiate?

Comment: The answer for Ln begins as: d/d(theta) (Ln(y)) = ? ... I currently have: = theta^2 sin theta + 2theta sin theta - 2 cos theta / theta^2 cos^2 theta

Comment: @DanielGarcia see the update

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to quotient rule is to rearrange to get $\sec \theta(1 + \frac 2{\theta}) $

Then you may use the derivative of $\sec \theta$, which is $\sec\theta \tan\theta$. You need product rule as well.

Logarithmic differentiation is possible here, but it's a needless complication. Don't use it unless the question wording forces you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic differentiation is entirely unnecessary here, but you should employ:
$$\ln\bigg(\frac pq\bigg)=\ln(p)-\ln(q)\implies\bigg[\ln\bigg(\frac pq\bigg)\bigg]'=[\ln(p)]'-[\ln(q)]'$$
and then:

$$Y'=Y\cdot[\ln( Y)]'$$

Comment: The answer entry box looks like this: d/dtheta (Ln (y)) =?